# PowerShell FTP fail not hitting Catch block

Tags: powershell, error-handling, ftp, try-catch

I have this script that I use to FTP up to a mainframe to download some data for reporting.

I am getting a username and password from user input.

I have everything wrapped in a `try/catch` block. For some reason I don't seem to be catching an error. If I type in bad creditentials I want it to error out and hit my `catch` block and write the appropriate error message, and stop the rest of my script from continuing.

I have looked around to try and find an answer, but nothing seems to be working. 
This is the error that is being thrown into my console when I type in bad login info (which is obviously expected).

```
ftp.exe : Login failed.
At C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\PS\script.ps1:348 char:5
+     ftp <<<<  -s:ftp.txt | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Login failed.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

It skips right over my catch block and continues to run my script.

Here is my the function I am running, slightly modified.

```
function FTPMainFrame{

try{

#re-assigning variables
$user = $username
$pass = $password

$pw = $pass | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
ConvertFrom-SecureString $pw | Out-File ftppass.txt -Encoding ASCII 

$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (Get-Content ftppass.txt)
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".",$pw)
$cred.GetNetworkCredential()|fl | Out-Null

# Template for FTP script
$Script = @" 
open XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
<username>
<password>
get 'SOME.FILES.1' C:\Users\$userName\Desktop\SomeFolder\data\data1.txt
get 'SOME.FILES.2' C:\Users\$userName\Desktop\SomeFolder\data\data2.txt
get 'SOME.FILES.3' C:\Users\$userName\Desktop\SomeFolder\data\data3.txt
get 'SOME.FILES.4' C:\Users\$userName\Desktop\SomeFolder\data\data4.txt
quit
"@

# Reconstitute stored password
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String (Get-Content ftppass.txt)
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential(".",$pw)
$passtext = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$Script = $Script -replace '<username>', $user
$Script = $Script -replace '<password>', $passtext
$Script | Out-File ftp.txt -Encoding ASCII

Write-Host "Running Batch..."

ftp -s:ftp.txt | Out-Null #error's here

#ftp -s:ftp.txt | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop 
#I've tried this and quite a few other things to force it to be a terminating error...
}
Catch{
    Write-Host "FTP Login Failed, please check your user name and password."

    $ErrorActionPreference = Stop  #should stop the rest of the script..
}
Remove-Item -Path .\ftp.txt
}
```

What can I do here to get it to hit my catch block, and stop running the script?

If my question is unclear or you need a little more info please feel free to ask.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You're complicating the error handling by using the command line FTP program.  You'll have better luck using dotnet methods (system.net.webclient, or Invoke-WebRequest).

Comment: @mjolinor hmm, ok I will look into that. Will that still work with FTP 'ing to a mainframe?

Comment: @mjolinor can you maybe explain how this is complicating my error handling?

Comment: It's running in a cmd process outside of Powershell.  Powershell is no longer in direct control of the error handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the automatic variable `$?` to check if the previous command executed successfully.

I would remove the `try..catch` and replace the `ftp.exe` call with:

```
# Redirect error output
ftp -s:ftp.txt 2> $null

if(-not $?) {
    # Display your message, and stop the script.
    throw "FTP Login Failed, please check your user name and password."
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I didn't know about `$?` so I am going to have to do some reading because it seems like it is incredible useless. I have one questions regarding this line here `ftp -s:ftp.txt 2> $null`. What exactly is the `..2> $null` doing here..?

Comment: @BigRabbit Yeah, see `help about_Automatic_Variables` for more info on `$?`. The `2> $null` redirects the stderr stream to `$null`. If you need to capture stdout as well you can add the `out-null` back in. To test, try `.{Write-Error test1;write-output test2} 2> $null | out-null` then remove either the `2> $null` or `| out-null`

Comment: Great, thank you for your help! Gave me some reading material for my commute. I will test both to get a better grasp on what is actually going on. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing! I should also note that `1>` or `>` can redirect stdout as well (i.e. `.{Write-Error test1;write-output test2} 1> $null 2> $null`)